# HTML + CSS issue, Chrome/Safari vs Firefox text positioning issue

Tags: html, css

Hello fellow webdesigners and webdesigner wannabes.

Know that I have tried to find a solution for my problem, but as I am quite new to this thing called CSS, it is a bit overwhelming to know what exactly I'm looking for here in terms of making my design compatible.

The text that I am placing inside a div:

http://jsfiddle.net/tsaulic/W22DC/67/

```
<div id="header-social-icons"><a href="http://test">C</a><a href="http://test">M</a><a href="http://test">F</a></div>
```

and my CSS

```
#header-social-icons {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Social Logos";
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

is rendering the same in Chrome/Safari, but it's rendering differently in Firefox. Chrome and Safari both kind of place it closer to the bottom of the div container, and Firefox does the opposite (top). I have tried using a solution from http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html and I am also using normalize.css (2.1.1)

Note that using both of those does nothing for my problem, it doesn't make it worse or any better.

What am I missing? I tried using margins, lowering the font size (not an overflow issue), increasing the height of the div container and many other things. :(

I want to achieve the text inside the container to be vertically centered. It's not centered in either of the browsers.

Please help.

Another note: All other header divs appear the same across all browsers, except one of my search fields which is positioned like 2px lower in Chrome/Safari than Firefox.

---

just an update: to make it clearer what the issue was... I just had to add the same line-height value as my height, as suggested by AnaMaria.

Like so:

```
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
```

Comment: Well, I did say "I am new" not "to this new thing called CSS" :D

Comment: Oh well. My bad then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is what you are loooking for...

```
vertical-align:middle
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W22DC/65/)

**Alternative solution:**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W22DC/66/)

Using line height method.

CSS

```
#header-social-icons {
    background-color:#fffdd0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px text-align: center;
}
```

Check these links for more info 
[LINK 1](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)
[LINK 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20091017204329/http://www.zann-marketing.com/developer/20050518/vertically-centering-text-using-css.html)

Comment: The jsfiddle snippet you posted in the comments of San's answer was what works perfectly for me. If you update this answer with it, I will accept it. Thanks again, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to the **container** `div`:

```
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
```

Example:

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; height: 500px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">    
    <div id="header-social-icons"><a href="http://test">C</a><a href="http://test">M</a><a href="http://test">F</a></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well try this :

```
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

Comment: not tring to be rude, But do you understand the difference between vertical(|) and Horizontal(-)

Answer (score 0):

I know you're approaching this via the CSS route, but have you considered formatting within a table?  Take a look at this fiddle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ninja1/H5DLm/)

HTML

```
<table id="header-social-icons">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://test">C</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://test">M</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://test">F</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#header-social-icons {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Arial";
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 28px;
}
```